# API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed: Not Found: Dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on importing CSV files from a Google Drive, through Apps Scripts into Big Query.
BUT, when the code gets to the part where it needs to send the job to BigQuery, it states that the dataset is not found - even though the correct dataset ID is already in the code.

Very much thank you!

Comment: Can you include your code in your question?

Comment: if the dataset id is correct, this could be a matter of the dataset location. Please share your code. Maybe you need to pass the dataset location explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of the google example code, this error that you indicate is more than a copy and paste.  However, validate that you have the following:

```
    const projectId = 'XXXXXXXX';
    const datasetId = 'YYYYYYYY';
    const csvFileId = '0BwzA1Orbvy5WMXFLaTR1Z1p2UDg';
    
    try {
         table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
         Logger.log('Table created: %s', table.id);
       } catch (error) {
         Logger.log('unable to create table');
       }
```

according to the documentation in the link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

It also validates that in the services tag you have the bigquery service enabled.